# How can I use a 'fast-writing' in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

For example, I want to create this code:

```
<ul id="nav">
    ....
</ul>
```

in other editors I can write smth like that: ul#nav
Can I use smth similar to this in WebStorm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. It's called Emmet (https://emmet.io/) and WebStorm supports standard Emmet abbreviations as well as such dynamic expanding.

WebStorm help pages:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-zen-coding-support.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/settings-emmet.html